# QML/QtQuick Binding delegate's property with ListView's currentIndex

Tags: qt, listview, delegates, qml

Inside the delegate, I bind Image's `source` property to ListView's `currentIndex` which determines which image to load.  This works great:

```
ListView {
    id: answerListView
    model: 5
    currentIndex: -1
    delegate: answerDelegate
}    

Component {
    id: answerDelegate
    Item {
        width: 100
        height: 100
        Image {
            source: answerListView.currentIndex === index
                        ? "selected.png" : "not_selected.png"
        }
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                answerListView.currentIndex = index
            }  
        }
        Component.onCompleted: {
            answerListView.currentIndex = 1; // doesn't work!!
        } 
    }
}
```

Since `currentIndex: -1`, it will always show `not_selected.png`.  To show `selected.png`, I change currentIndex in `Component.onLoaded` inside delegate.

I was expecting image to load `selected.png` since currentIndex was updated.
What is the correct way and what am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: For me it works fine, once I edit the code, that I have dimensions for the stuff. To truly verify your problem, please make your example a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that I just need to copy your code and paste it in the QtCreator main.qml. As example-images you might use urls pointing e.g. to images from stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, new guess:
You want to have the posibility to select multiple `Items`. As `currentIndex` only stores one value, which is the value you assigned it last, you can use it to mark only one `Item`.

Therefore you need to find another way to store your selection. You might for example have a property in the delegate: `property bool selected: false` which you set to true upon selection.

The problem with this solution is, that it only works if all `Items` are instantiated at all times. As soon as one `Item` will be destroyed again, the information will be lost, and uppon the next creation, the selection/unselection is undone.

The better way would be to introduce a role in your model, that stores the selection outside of the *non-persistant* delegates for you:

```
ListView {
    id: answerListView
    model: lm
    delegate: answerDelegate
    width: 100
    height: 220
}
ListModel {
    id: lm
    ListElement { selected: false }
    ListElement { selected: false }
    ListElement { selected: false }
    ListElement { selected: false }
    ListElement { selected: false }
}

Component {
    id: answerDelegate
    Item {
        width: 100
        height: 100
        Image {
            anchors.fill: parent
            source: model.selected ? "selected.png" : "notselected.png"
        }

        Text {
            text: (model.selected ? 'selected ' : 'notselected ')
        }
        Component.onCompleted: {
            model.selected = true // doesn't work!!
        }
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                model.selected = !model.selected
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another option would probably be a [ItemSelectionModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-itemselectionmodel.html), but I don't know atm, how it works.

Otherwise your example works as expected:
The `Item` with `index 1` is shown, and displays the Image `selected.png`. All other `Item`s are not shown (for the `ListView` is to small) but if the would be shown, they would show `notselected.png` for the `answerListView.currentIndex` is not equal to their index.

Comment: TY.  I've tried to set `answerListView.currentIndex = index` in Component.onCompleted.  But doesn't work.  =(  This should set all the delegate's image to display `selected.png`.   I understand `MouseArea` issue, and updated code to clarify.

Comment: **ALL** the delegate's? The `answerListView.currentIndex` holds exactley one value. And exactely the one Item with the corresponding value is displayed as `selected`. If you want to have multiple selected `Items` you should have a role in your model `selected` or a property in your delegated `selected` that handels the selection. Or a selectionModel but I have not looked into how this works.

Comment: TY again.  Your last comment really helped me, realized that setting the `currentIndex` inside my delegate doesn't make sense at all.  I've moved it inside `ListView` and it's all working as expected.